# how call a prototype function with jquery? or call prototype and jquery in footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

for SEO reasons I try to descent js to footer in a big website make with prototype and jquery.

I try to encapsulate the jquery and prototype propertyes in the body to run after in footer I keep the variables and functions to make interactions.

with jquery works fine but i have problems with prototype.

here the idea in psedocode

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var domReadyQueue = []; // this var encapsule all js in the page
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    some Div and other tricks

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            domReadyQueue.push(function ($) {
                new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
            })
            //]]>
        </script>

        some Div and other tricks

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var loginForm;
        domReadyQueue.push(function($){
            loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
            $('login-email').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost); //here is the error
            $('login-password').observe('keypress', bindLoginPost);
        })
        function bindLoginPost(evt){
            if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
                loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
        function onepageLogin(button)
        {
            if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
                button.disabled = true;
                loginForm.submit();
            }
        }
    //]]>
    </script>


    some Div and other tricks


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function(){
            while (domReadyQueue.length) {
                domReadyQueue.shift()(jQuery);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

in console the error say

console error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).observe is not a function

exist a way to call prototype code with jquery?

exist a way in prototype to encapsulate? i can use this var to jquery and use other to prototype.

Maybe another idea to put jquery anf prototype in the footer? with a less impact in the rest of code?

the website have millons of lines, and works, change or re-thinks all is very complicate.

Comment: It's because jQuery function $(...) is called before it's javascript file is loaded. please include your <script> tag of jquery.js at head.

Comment: no the var domReadyQueue encapsule the jquery, the function run in the call call before /body after call jquery in footer, and how i say, the jquery part works fine

Comment: As observe() is a prototype function, I'm guessing that you're using any other libray which is a 3rd party library that removes prototype and replaces it with jquery. You'll need to adapt the javascript to work with jquery. I don't know what other js you are loading, so this may be the issue.

Comment: well no, is the encapsulate, because if I put jquery and prototype in header and i retire the var domReadyQueue  all works, I think my problem is because i run domReadyQueue.shift()(jQuery); how JQUERY and inside is a problem when arrive to prototype code... jquery can't read i check and i call prototype in first time how in my pseudo code

Comment: Why are you passing `jQuery` if your code expects to get the prototype `$`?

Comment: that is the problem I expects the 2